# jquery datatables en semantic no me muestra el campo de busqueda

Tags: jquery, datatables, semantic-ui

Tengo una página web donde cargo una tabla con registros y estoy utilizando el dataTables Table plug-in for jQuery sobre semantic-ui.
Resulta que en otra página me carga la tabla con todos los controles: mostrar determinada cantidad de registros, paginación de registros y cuadro de busqueda rápida.
[image: esto esta bien]

En otra página, estos controles no se muestran:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo extraño es que la tabla toma los estilos propios del plugin... 
A alguien le ha pasado el mismo problema ?

Comment: A mi se me presento ese error, y lo que tenia malo era la ruta del plugin datables, pero si hacia referencia al css de el datatable  por eso la tabla tomaba el estilo del plugin.

Comment: sabes que creo que el problema esta ahi !!!... una pagina que tenia ese error apuntaba al js que habia bajado, lo reemplace por la ruta cdn y lo solucione pero otra página que tiene ese error, persiste aun cambiando el cdn... no se por que pasa eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATENCION !!!! 
ENCONTRE CUAL ES EL ERROR... 
Este error se produce en el plugin de datatables, cuando existe una diferencia entre la cantidad de columnas que se definen con las etiquetas  y las etiquetas 

Corregí ese pequeño detalle y voilá... santo remedio... todo empezó a funcionar perfectamente !!!